# Deploying Java Application in Tomcat/Glassfish

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, struts2, struts

I have an issue and I cannot solve it, even if I know that Maven deals with it. I have been looking for a solution for a long time and I cannot find it anywhere. I even tried to find some Maven tutorials but I haven't found anything yet.

So the problem appears when I want to deploy my application to Tomcat. Everything goes smooth until I want to modify something in it. It has a lot of images, files, video files, because it's a small portal. Every time I want to modify something I have to backup all this stuff in my computer and only after that i can run the undeploy process so that I can upload the new .WAR and it gets very unconfortable as the data grows. I would be very thankful if someone has a solution to this problem. My projects are performed in Struts/Struts2+Spring+Hibernate. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you build your application and why do you need to backup "all this stuff in my computer". Are you using Ant or Maven?

Comment: Because all the information I have is in the build folder of the WAR file, and when I do undeploy application from tomcat, it deletes everything in it, including the build folder.

Comment: The best practice for web applications is to keep your source data (code, images, etc.) in a separate directory and use a build process, either with Ant or with Maven which copies all the necessary information into a war file or "exploded" war file. Then you deploy this war file to the container and free to do whatever with it. This tutorial: http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2010/spring-hibernate-maven-struts2-integration-tutorial looks like a good starting point.

Comment: I have not managed to know Ant and Maven yet, that's why I never used it, I will try your solution to, thank you

Comment: IMO that way of doing things is an accident waiting to happen - you really need to bring some sanity into you development workflow.

Comment: Nevermind I answered a netbeans question for you earlier.  I don't understand how you can have this issue.  You just edit your project (like you would any project in Netbeans) and when you go to run it (it you set it up as a web application like we talked about in your last question) it will ask what web server you would like to run it on (you did download netbeans bundled with Tomcat and Glassfish right?) any ways it will prompt for you to pick one when you run (it will ask if you want to remember this) and then it will deploy. It will make the war and put where it needs to be for you.

Comment: You don't understand what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a content repository for images and external resources; look at LifeRay or Alfresco or Sling, or Communique for solutions in this space, or look at JackRabbit for implementing the client of a repository yourself. It's actually pretty easy, and very scalable.

Comment: Yes, but if to take this solution, it is necessary to have separate server for this content, correct me if I did not understand something. I'm looking for something like a SVN, I mean, do something new in your project, then you commit it, and so on

Comment: Why would it be necessary to have another server? JCR is deployable as a jar for your own project (see Jackrabbit), or as another web application that YOUR application can access (see Sling, et al.) No need for another server whatsoever.